# Java library for creating straight skeleton?

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

I have as an input a 2D polygon with holes, and I need to find it's straight skeleton, like in the picture:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cgal.org](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.2/doc_html/cgal_manual/Straight_skeleton_2/exterior_skeleton.png))</sub>

Maybe there is a good Java library for it?

And if not, can you point me to the good explanation of the algorithm, so I could implement it myself? (I haven't found good resources on Google)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote this a little while back. Not sure if it's robust enough.
https://github.com/twak/campskeleton

(edited for 2018...)

Comment: Good one. But I did notice a bug - sometimes it seems like the skeleton misses a segment.

Comment: I played around with your library, and it is great! Now I only need to find a way of extracting skeleton lines from faces. :)

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/~dbelan2/roofs/roofs.html which contains an applet.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use the [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html).  It is a very capable library that I've used on a number of projects - never for straight skeleton, but it may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Ah.  I see that "[Straight Skeleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton)" is a technical term.  The wikipedia article references several algorithms.  Have you looked at those?

---

As I understand it, you have a (convex?) polygon.  From it, you subtract 1 or more (potentially non-convex) polygons. You want to turn the result into a set of polygons without holes.  Are there extra rules that you're trying to apply?

I have a hard time coming up with a set of rules from the example that you provided.  The outer polygons are non-convex; so it doesn't seem like you're trying to find a convex set to represent the result (which is a relatively common task).

If you could use the breakdown shown below, the algorithm is pretty simple.  Can you clarify?

[image: Triangularized shape]

Answer (score -2):

Can I ask u what is your purpose for finding Straight skeleton? Is it personal or commercial? I would be interested in knowing how you r using it to solve real time problems? I do have a java library that does that. My algorithm is listed here http://web.stcloudstate.edu/rsarnath/skeleton/definition.htm

Comment: Commercial. In my case, I was actually seeking a way of "thinning" the polygon. Straight skeleton looked good, but too slow - I needed to get that "center line" for complex polygons (made of many thousands points) in real-time (< 1 sec) on weak machines. So in the end, I settled on creating constrained Delaunay triangulation of the polygon, and connecting the triangle centers - it gave me pretty good approximation of "center line".