# How to apply Straight Skeleton Algorithm in android

Tags: android, algorithm, android-layout, genetic-algorithm

I have a requirement like this. Here is my home class snapshot.

[image]

It contains several shop shape. And for that I have used this code :

```
ArrayList<Point> points2 = new ArrayList<Point>();

points2.add(vertex.Get(20, 0));

points2.add(vertex.Get(44, 0));

points2.add(vertex.Get(44, 25));

points2.add(vertex.Get(20, 25));

Polygon view1 = new Polygon(context, points2, android.R.color.holo_orange_dark, R.color.background_light, floor != 0);

view1.setId(0);

views.add(view1);           

addView(view1);
```

This is for static number of shapes.Now requirement is such that number of shapes will be dynamic.and for that i don't need to use same code as above.Client has told to implement Straight Skeleton Algorithm.

I googled about it and found some help for same algorithm implementation in core java.

[Java library for creating straight skeleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640040/java-library-for-creating-straight-skeleton)

This issue explains in java.I tried it out,that is totaly in core java.I need to implement it on android.and Never worked on such issue before.Need some help if some one have already implemented it on android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

https://code.google.com/p/campskeleton/

From this answer:
[Java library for creating straight skeleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640040/java-library-for-creating-straight-skeleton)